# CSS: top border visible when bottom border and radius are set

Tags: html, css

When an element has border radius and border-bottom, there's a top border (barely) visible even though it shouldn't be. Seems to be an artefact of some kind of sub-pixel rendering.

How can this be mitigated?

[image: barely visible top border that shouldn't be here]

https://codepen.io/mmiszy/pen/ExRXOdy

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: black;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I am on chrome and this is not visible to me even when I zoom into the page. Which browser did you try this on?

Comment: Chrome on MacOS, Safari on MacOS and iOS. Multiple people confirmed this problem on Discord before I’ve created this question. You can see the problem on the attached screenshot.

Comment: I also can't see it (neither on Firefox nor Edge)

Comment: So weird, I agree with your poroblem could be because of your browser or os, because I see on chrome and edge is just a round border bottom

Comment: I've seen some weird things happen on 4K monitors. Sometimes I'll move a browser window between a 1920x1080 secondary monitor and a 4K primary monitor and there are some weird issues with borders and backgrounds not always lining up on the 4K monitor with a tiny gap visible between them.  This might be a similar case.

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: black;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: There's even a bigger problem now, have you even tested your code?